# tsqlt spyProcedure with multiple output parameters

Tags: parameters, output, tsqlt

There is a related post to my question dealing with a single output parameter, but I cannot find a way to apply that to my procedure which has multiple output parameters.

An overview of the procedure I would like to spy is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[wms_whse_check_serialNumber]
  @Command Json
, @operWarningMessage_notExists exception OUTPUT
, @operWarningMessage_notInInventory exception OUTPUT
<...>
```

This code works:

```
EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure @ProcedureName = N'dbo.wms_whse_check_serialNumber', 
  @CommandToExecute = N'SET @operWarningMessage_notExists = NULL;';
```

However, I would like to specify both output parameters.  If I try:

```
EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure @ProcedureName = N'dbo.wms_whse_check_serialNumber', 
  @CommandToExecute = N'SET @operWarningMessage_notExists = NULL, @operWarningMessage_notInInventory = NULL;';
```

I get: `(Error) Incorrect syntax near ','.[15,1]{wms_whse_check_serialNumber,1}`

I have fiddled with it quite a bit, and cannot come up with a syntax that will succeed.  What have I missed?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Sebastian!  Very grateful for tsqlt and for your support of it!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `SET` with a `SELECT`  as in:

```
     EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure @ProcedureName = N'dbo.wms_whse_check_serialNumber', 
       @CommandToExecute = N'SELECT @operWarningMessage_notExists = NULL, @operWarningMessage_notInInventory = NULL;';
```

**Explanation**:

The `SET` command can only set one variable at a time. You can use multiple `SET` statements, or as shown above, use `SELECT` instead to assign multiple variables at once.

**Sidenote**:

There is nothing stopping you from using multiple statements in the `@CommandToExecute` parameter above, so this would also be a working solution:

```
     EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure @ProcedureName = N'dbo.wms_whse_check_serialNumber', 
       @CommandToExecute = N'SET @operWarningMessage_notExists = NULL; SET @operWarningMessage_notInInventory = NULL;';
```